# move files that have the same name of the file they contain

Tags: linux, shell

Someone very clever (feel irony?) has extracted more than 6000 archives in their own directories, but sometimes the archive contain one file: the same name of the directory it contains.

Example:

```
mydir(0001)/mydir(0001).txt
mydir(ZREZ)/mydir(ZREZ).txt
mydir(AAEZ)/mydir(AAREZ).txt
mydir(AAEZ)/otherfile.txt
mydir(QQQQ)/mydir(QQQQ).txt
...
```

Is there a fast way (Unix shell) to compare the file (if there's only one file) and the directory where it's in, and if it's the same (without the extension), move it one directory above and remove the (now empty) directory?

So I should get:

```
mydir(0001).txt
mydir(ZREZ).txt
mydir(AAEZ)/mydir(AAREZ).txt
mydir(AAEZ)/otherfile.txt
mydir(QQQQ).txt
...
```

Comment: Take a look at `dirname` and `basename` commands

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you. It would have taken you 2 femtoseconds to watch my profile before commenting like that. You would have found out that I'm not that lazy guy your answer suggests. If I'm asking it's because I didn't find anything valuable on the web, and I thought someone may already have done that. Hopefully not all people think "DIY, lazy guy" (just writing down the polite version you may think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a script like this from the parent directory of all those 6000 directories/files:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r d; do
    n=$(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo . \; | wc -l)
    f="${d}/${d}.txt"
    [[ $n -eq 1 && -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "$d/../" && rmdir "$d"
done < <(find . -type d ! -name '.' -print0)
```

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work. Are you sure it's `-exec echo .` and not `-exec echo {}`?

Comment: You can run that find command separately. That is a way to count all the files and directories of a given sub-directory. Try running `find "./subdir" -maxdepth 1 -exec echo . \; | wc -l` to see what you get.

Comment: Ok thank you but it doesn't do it recursively, it just stops at the first level. Maybe it's because I don't know how to inject / precise all directories?

Comment: It wasn't clear if all these dirs/files are at same level or in nested sub directories, that's why I wrote this for one level only. It can be modified to go deep also. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. A bit simpler than anubhava's script, but still careful about only moving files and removing dirs if that's the only content.

```
for x in *; do
  if [[ $(find "$x" | sed 1d | head -n2) == "$x/$x.txt" ]]; then
    mv "$x/$x.txt" . && rmdir "$x"
  fi
done
```

You can cut-n-paste this to the command line in the parent dir. It loops over all files in that dir (`for x in *`) and if any of them is itself a directory containing only the single file `$x/$x.txt` then it will move the file and remove the directory.

Comment: What would happen if you encountered: `mydir(0001)/mydir(0002).txt`?

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to use it recursively? (= send all my files to the script)?

Comment: David, in that case it wouldn't move the file, as it shouldn't according to the OP's description.

Comment: Olivier, assuming I understand correctly that you unpacked all the archives into their own directories under a single parent dir, then you can just cut-n-paste this on the command-line inside the parent dir.  (Even though it's multiple lines, it will cut-n-paste properly in bash, which I assumed is your shell.)  I'll add a bit more description if that helps to demystify how it works.

Comment: Tried what you said: it's instantaneous and does nothing.

Comment: Okay, fixed it. In the case of the single `$x/$x.txt` case, the find command emits two lines, where the first line is the directory name itself. I hadn't accounted for that. </sheepish>

Answer (score 0):

Here's my script, based on Anubhava's first answer. Sorry for the beginner's style:

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop & print a folder recusively,
folder_recurse() {
    for i in "$1"/*;do
        if [ -d "$i" ];then
            n=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -exec echo . \; | wc -l)
            d=$(readlink -f "${i}")
            g=$d"/"$(basename "$i")".epub"
            if [[ $n -eq 2 && -f "$g" ]]; then
                echo "Doing: $i"
                mv "$g" "$d/.."
                rmdir "$d"
            fi
            folder_recurse "$i"
    done
}


# try get path from param
path=""
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    path=$1;
else
    path="/tmp"
fi

echo "base path: $path"
folder_recurse $path
```

Comment: You should not really do that. This is pretty much what my answer also had. That's not fair to posters who spend their time and come up with answers. You could post this as an edit to your question but removing the acceptance mark is not what rest of the SO community does.

Comment: Ok I checked your answer as valid `:/`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a one-liner within the parent directory:

```
for i in */*; do [ -f "${i%/*}/${i%/*}.txt" ] && mv "$i" . && rm -d "${i%/*}"; done
```

Since there has been interest in a solution that function equally on BSD where there is no `rm -d`, the same can be accomplished with:

```
for i in */*; do [ -f "${i%/*}/${i%/*}.txt" ] && mv "$i" . && [ -z "$(ls -A "${i%/*}")" ] && rm -r "${i%/*}"; done
```

Which, following the `mv` check whether the remaining directory is empty, and if so, then removes the directory, otherwise leaving the directory unchanged.

**output:**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Aug 25 16:20 mydir(AAEZ)
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Aug 25 16:20 mydir(0001).txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Aug 25 16:20 mydir(QQQQ).txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Aug 25 16:20 mydir(ZREZ).txt

mydir\(AAEZ\)/
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Aug 25 16:20 mydir(AAREZ).txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Aug 25 16:20 otherfile.txt
```

If needed, you can also test that the directory is empty after moving the file -- before deleting the directory. **Shown**

Comment: In the example given, this will remove the dir `mydir(AAEZ)` even though it contains `otherfile.txt`.

Comment: No, there is no file named `mydir(AAEZ)` -- but point well taken, I dropped a note at the end of the answer.

Comment: No, you are wrong. The code functions exactly as it was requested. Your hypothetical is accounted for in the note. You can always invent some case that isn't protected against and wasn't requested. If that's your thing -- fine.

Comment: In my haste I misread the example data. Then I hastily deleted my comment based on my misreading. So much haste waste! Regardless, your scriptlet makes a poor and potentially destructive assumption based on example data that the OP says represents a much larger library of data. There's no reason for that assumption.

Comment: OP is on Linux, there is no `rm -d` since this is a BSDism.

Comment: Then we need to add `&& [ -z $(ls -A "${i%/*}") ] && rm -r "${i%/*}"` as the ending of the command. That will check that the directory is empty after `mv` and if so, then remove the directory leaving other files unchanged.